# MOSS 2007: Adding Filter to ListView web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts, moss

I have been dropped into a sharepoint 2007 project, and i have relatively little experience with altering existing webparts.

My first task is to add a filter to two out of three columns in a list view. My Lead Dev suggests trying to add a jquery combo-box filter, and another dev suggests extending the web part and overriding some of the functionality.

What i think is a good option is to change the context menu for the list view headers, so that instead of "Show Filter Choices" bringing up a standard dropdownlist that only responds to the first letter, it would have a jquery combobox. And maybe if the business requests it, change the wording of that option.

My question to you is, what would be a good path to take on this? Also, what resources are there besides traipsing around books and blogs are there to guide an sp newbie to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script>
        google.load("jquery", "1.2.6");
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function() { 

            $(document).ready(function()
            { 
                jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
                containsIgnoreCase: "(a.textContent||a.innerText||jQuery(a).text()||'').toLowerCase().indexOf((m[3]||'').toLowerCase())>=0"
    });

    $("table.ms-listviewtable tr.ms-viewheadertr").each(function()
    {
        if($("td.ms-vh-group", this).size() > 0)
        {
            return; 
        }
        var tdset = "";
        var colIndex = 0;
        $(this).children("th,td").each(function()
        {
            if($(this).hasClass("ms-vh-icon"))
            {
                // attachment
                tdset += "<td></td>";
            }
            else
            {
                // filterable
                tdset += "<td><input type='text' class='vossers-filterfield' filtercolindex='" + colIndex + "' /></td>"; 
            }
            colIndex++;
        });
        var tr = "<tr class='vossers-filterrow'>" + tdset + "</tr>";
        $(tr).insertAfter(this);
    }); 

        $("input.vossers-filterfield")
            .css("border", "1px solid #7f9db9")
            .css("width", "100%")
            .css("margin", "2px")
            .css("padding", "2px")
            .keyup(function()
        { 
            var inputClosure = this;
            if(window.VossersFilterTimeoutHandle)
            {
                clearTimeout(window.VossersFilterTimeoutHandle);
            }
            window.VossersFilterTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(function()
            {
            var filterValues = new Array();
            $("input.vossers-filterfield", $(inputClosure).parents("tr:first")).each(function()
            { 
                if($(this).val() != "") 
                {
                    filterValues[$(this).attr("filtercolindex")] = $(this).val();
                }
            }); 
            $(inputClosure).parents("tr.vossers-filterrow").nextAll("tr").each(function()
            {
                var mismatch = false;
                $(this).children("td").each(function(colIndex)
                {
                    if(mismatch) return;
                    if(filterValues[colIndex])
                    {
                        var val = filterValues[colIndex];
                        // replace double quote character with 2 instances of itself
                        val = val.replace(/"/g, String.fromCharCode(34) + String.fromCharCode(34)); 
                        if($(this).is(":not(:containsIgnoreCase('" + val + "'))"))
                        {
                            mismatch = true;
                        } 
                    }
                });
                if(mismatch)
                {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).show();
                } 
                }); 
            }, 250);
        });
    });
});
```

It will need to be added to the page via a content editor web part.